# Not able to run automation test on windows 10 edge looks like jquery selector is not working

Tags: jquery, selenium-webdriver, automation, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I am trying to run my automation tests on windows 10 edge and at the moment it's not able to create the jquery element and return the element so that I can perform some actions on it (like sendkeys or click on it etc...)
below is some sample flow of my test. basically we check for Jquery exists or not if doesn't we inject http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js from last block of code I have included here.

```
if (localDriver.Equals("internetexplorer"))
                    {                  

                       EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
                        options.PageLoadStrategy = EdgePageLoadStrategy.Eager;
                        driver = new EdgeDriver("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Web Driver", options);
                        driver.Url = UrlHelper.HomeUrl;
                        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
                    }
 this._context.Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
if (this.DeleteAllCookies)                            this._context.Driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
driver.UserNameTextField.Clear(); --- this statement has to use below statement and create the web element
 internal WebControl TicketIdTextField { get { return this.CreateControl("#TicketId"); } }
 #region Create Control
        public WebControl CreateControl(string jQuerySelector)
        {
            return this.CreateControl<WebControl>(jQuerySelector);
        }

        public T CreateControl<T>(string jQuerySelector) where T : WebControl
        {
            return this.CreateControl<T>(WebControl.SearchNames.JQuerySelector, jQuerySelector);
        }

        public new T CreateControl<T>(params string[] nameValuePairs) where T : WebControl
        {
            return base.CreateControl<T>(nameValuePairs);
        }

        public new T CreateControl<T>(IEnumerable<SearchProperty> searchProperties) where T : WebControl
        {
            return base.CreateControl<T>(searchProperties);
        }
        #endregion

 #region Create Control
        public T CreateControl<T>(params string[] nameValuePairs) where T : Control
        {
            if ((nameValuePairs.Length % 2) != 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("CreateControl needs to have even number of pairs. (Mod 2)", "nameValuePairs");
            }
            var searchProperties = new List<SearchProperty>();
            for (int i = 0; i < nameValuePairs.Length; i = (int)(i + 2))
            {
                searchProperties.Add(new SearchProperty(nameValuePairs[i], nameValuePairs[i + 1]));
            }

            return this.CreateControl<T>(searchProperties);
        }
public virtual T CreateControl<T>(IEnumerable<SearchProperty> searchProperties) where T : Control
        {
            var control = Control.CreateInstance<T>(this.Context, this);
            control.SearchProperties.AddRange(searchProperties);
            return control;
        }
        #endregion

  #region RawControl
        private object _rawControl;

        public object RawControl
        {
            get
            {
                /* Always Search Feature
                 * --------------------- 
                 * 
                 * If there is a property in the search properties 
                 * set for "Always Search" then it must always call this.Find()
                 * 
                 * If the global property is set for always search, then 
                 * it must call this.Find()
                 * 
                 */

                var alwaysSearch = this.SearchProperties.Any(x => x.Name == Control.SearchNames.AlwaysSearch);
                if (this._rawControl == null || (this._isHightlighting == false && (Playback.AlwaysSearch || alwaysSearch)))
                {
                    this.Find();
                }

                return this._rawControl;
            }
        } 

public object ExecuteScript(string script, params object[] args)
        {
            var javaScriptExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)this.Driver;

            if(CheckjQueryExists)
            {
                var timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
                var timeoutThreshold = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(timeout);

                var isJQueryUndefined = new Func<bool>(() => (bool)javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("return (typeof $ === 'undefined')"));
                if (isJQueryUndefined())
                {
                    javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript(@"
                        var scheme =  window.location.protocol;
                        if(scheme != 'https:')
                            scheme = 'http:';

                        var script = document.createElement('script');
                        script.type = 'text/javascript';
                        script.src = scheme + '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js'; 
                        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
                    ");

                    while (isJQueryUndefined())
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);

                        //Don't test forever.. bomb out after a bit.
                        if (DateTime.UtcNow > timeoutThreshold)
                            throw new TimeoutException(string.Format("Checking jQuery exists timed out after {0} seconds.", timeout.TotalSeconds));
                    }
                }
            }

            return javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript(script, args);
        }
driver.username="someuser";
```

Comment: what is your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webdriver MS Edge browser does not get URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657951/webdriver-ms-edge-browser-does-not-get-url)