# Webdriver MS Edge browser does not get URL

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I tried to navigate URL with MS Edge Browser but it giving me error. 
My Environment is as follows:
Windows: 10 64x pro.
Browser: MS Edge 25.10586.0.0
Selenium WebDriver: 2.48.2

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;

public class edgeBrowser {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver",
            "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Web Driver\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

  }
}
```

MS edge browser opens but it does not navigate to google.com and I received following error

> Received a request for http://localhost:17347/session
>
> Existing Microsoft Edge process (pid: 64400) terminated forcibly.
>
> Waiting for new request...
>
> Received a request for http://localhost:17347/shutdown
>
> Stopping server.
>
> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: null (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>
> Command duration or timeout: 6.79 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue (if I recall) and the solution for me was to install the driver presented as:

> For the latest preview build from the Windows Insider Program, install
>   this version of Microsoft WebDriver

Listed here:
[WebDriver for Microsoft Edge (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt188085(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Yeah it works, I have installed (For Windows 10 Fall 2015 Update, install Microsoft WebDriver Fall 2015 Update.) and Edge is working and navigating my URL.
Thank you buddy.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and after so much of struggle we found the solution which works fine for us. 
Microsoft has made Microsoft WebDriver a Feature on Demand (FoD) to make it easier to get the right version for your device.
The simplest way to get started is to enable Developer Mode. Open the Settings app and go to “Update & Security,” “For developers,” and select “Developer Mode.” The appropriate version of WebDriver will be automatically installed.

You can also install a standalone version of WebDriver in one of two ways:

Search “Manage optional features” from Start, then select “Add a Feature,” “WebDriver.”
Install via DISM by running the following command in an elevated command prompt:DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0

You can checkout the complete steps in this blog : https://techminionsite.com/fix-for-microsoft-webdriver-windows-10-issue/